# What does "load" do in Django Templates?

Tags: python, django, function, django-templates, templatetags

As "load" is far too generic for searching:

1. What is the purpose of "load" and what does it do in this particular case? - in a template file, base_weblog.html,

   `{% load weblog %}{% render_month_links %}`
2. Are some naming conventions used in order for "load" to
   do its job? E.g. names of folders and/or files and/or
   class names?
3. Where is the documentation for "load" and can you elaborate?

---

Details:

The example is from the source for
http://www.djangoproject.com/ - direct download URL is
through http://shrinkster.com/17g8.

Partial folder structure (items with no file extension are folders):

```
django_website

  apps
    accounts
    aggregator
    blog
      urls.py
      models.py
        class Entry(models.Model)

      templatetags
        weblog.py
    contact
    docs

  templates
    base_weblog.html

    aggregator
    blog
      entry_archive.html
      entry_archive_year.html
      month_links_snippet.html
      entry_archive_month.html
      entry_detail.html
      entry_snippet.html
      entry_archive_day.html
    comments
    contact
    docs
    feeds
    flatfiles
    flatpages
    registration
```

Comment: make sure that blog.templatetags is in your INSTALLED_APPS tuple in settings.py. That fixed it for me.

Comment: load data from custom_filter.py file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"weblog" after "load" (in template file `django_website/templates/base_weblog.html`) refers to file `weblog.py` in folder `django_website/apps/blog/templatetags`. Folder `templatetags` must be named exactly that and must contain a file named `__init__.py` (question 2).

"load" makes the custom template tags (`render_latest_blog_entries` and `render_month_links` in this case) available for use in templates, `django_website\templates\base_weblog.html` in this case. "Load" is a security and performance function.

Answer (score 15):

[`load`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#load):

Load a custom template tag set.

See [Custom tag and filter libraries](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

[load tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#load) can load [built-in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/) and [custom](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) Django template tags and filters by setting the files in `load` tag.

For example of [a custom Django template tag and filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/), create `templatetags` folder with `__init__.py`(Empty file) and `custom_tags.py` in `core` folder where `settings.py` is as shown below, then don't forget to restart server to apply `custom_tags.py` to Django project. *Other names are fine for `custom_tags.py` and according to my experiments, `custom_tags.py` works without `__init__.py`(Empty file) but basically, it is better to create `__init__.py`(Empty file) just under `templatetags` folder by following what [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) says:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-templatetags # Here
 |     |-__init__.py
 |     └-custom_tags.py
 |-templates
 |  └-index.html
 |-app1
 └-app2
```

And, don't forget to set `core` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` to apply `custom_tags.py` to Django project as shown below. *Setting `core` to `INSTALLED_APPS` also can collect the static files in `core` folder to the root Django Project folder with `python manage.py collectstatic`. I recommend to set `core` to `INSTALLED_APPS` before you start building your Django Project:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'core', # Here
    'app1',
    'app2',
]
```

Then, create `uppercase` and `lowercase` tags in `custom_tags.py` as shown below. *You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76246817/register-simple-tag-vs-register-tag-vs-register-inclusion-tag-in-django-templ/76246818#76246818) explaining `@register.simple_tag`:

```py
# "core/templatetags/custom_tags.py"

from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.simple_tag
def uppercase(arg):
    return arg.upper()

@register.filter
def lowercase(arg):
    return arg.lower()
```

Then, you need to set the file `custom_tags` by omitting `.py` in load tag to use `uppercase` and `lowercase` tags as shown below:

```
# "templates/index.html"

{% load custom_tags %}

{% uppercase "Hello World" %} # HELLO WORLD
{{ "Hello World" | lowercase }} # hello world
```

And, you can also create the folders like `app1` and `app2` with `__init__.py`(Empty file) and `custom_tags.py` in `templatetags` folder as shown below. *Other names are fine for `app1` and `app2` folders and according to my experiments, `custom_tags.py` in `app1` and `app2` folders doesn't work without `__init__.py`(Empty file) so `__init__.py`(Empty file) must be created just under `app1` and `app2` folders:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-templatetags
 |     |-app1 # Here
 |     |  |-__init__.py
 |     |  └-custom_tags.py
 |     |-app2 # Here
 |     |  |-__init__.py
 |     |  └-custom_tags.py
 |     |-__init__.py
 |     └-custom_tags.py
 |-templates
 |  └-index.html
 |-app1
 └-app2
```

Then, you need to set the file `custom_tags` following the folders `app1` and `app2` in `load` tag to use the tags defined in `app1/custom_tags.py` and `app2/custom_tags.py` as shown below:

```
# "templates/index.html"
                   #  ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓     ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓
{% load custom_tags app1.custom_tags app2.custom_tags %}

# ...
```

And, if there are the same tags like `uppercase` through multiple files as shown below:

```py
# "core/templatetags/custom_tags.py"

@register.simple_tag
def uppercase(arg):
    return arg.upper()
```

```py
# "core/templatetags/app1/custom_tags.py"

@register.simple_tag
def uppercase(arg):
    return arg.upper() + " app1"
```

```py
# "core/templatetags/app2/custom_tags.py"

@register.simple_tag
def uppercase(arg):
    return arg.upper() + " app2"
```

Then, the `uppercase` tag of the last file set in `load` tag is used

```
# "templates/index.html"
                                    #  ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓
{% load custom_tags app1.custom_tags app2.custom_tags %}

{% uppercase "Hello World" %} # HELLO WORLD app2
```

Lastly, you can create multiple `templatetags` folders through multiple app folders `app1` and `app2` in addition to `core` folder as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-templatetags # Here
 |     |-__init__.py
 |     └-custom_tags.py
 |-templates
 |  └-index.html
 |-app1
 |  └-templatetags # Here
 |     |-__init__.py
 |     └-custom_tags.py
 └-app2
    └-templatetags # Here
       |-__init__.py
       └-custom_tags.py
```

However, I recommend to create only one `templatetags` folder in `core` folder because there are 3 reasons as shown below:

1. It is easier to manage only one `templatetags` folder in `core` folder than managing multiple `templatetags` folders through multiple app folders.
2. For Django Admin, there is no folder to create `templatetags` folder so `core` folder is the most reasonable place to do it for Django Admin.

And, the 3rd reason is because through multiple `templatetags` folders, if there are multiple same name files like `custom_tags.py` as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-templatetags
 |     |-__init__.py
 |     └-custom_tags.py # Here
 |-templates
 |  └-index.html
 |-app1
 |  └-templatetags
 |     |-__init__.py
 |     └-custom_tags.py # Here
 └-app2
    └-templatetags # Here
       |-__init__.py
       └-custom_tags.py # Here
```

Then, only one file is loaded in Django Templates but I don't know which file to be loaded according to my experiments as shown below:

```
# "templates/index.html"
                             
{% load custom_tags %} # I don't know which `custom_tags.py` is loaded.
```