# Django admin custom template tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, templatetags

I'm trying to customize my admin panel. I have copied `change_list.html` to the proper subfolder which is `templates -> admin -> model -> change_list.html`

While I customize the `change_list.html`, I'd like to use a templatetag but I'm not sure where to put my custom template tag library.

When I put it under `django/contrib/admin/templatetags/`, it works fine but I want to keep it in my own project tree.

Do you have any idea?

Note: I have also load my template tag in `change_list.html` as

```
{% load adminmedia admin_list i18n grp_tags myproject_tags %}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do **not** modify or add anything to directory containing Django (do not modify Django!). Keep everything in your project directory (like in [the manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout)).

Admin templates are exactly the same as non-admin templates and you use custom template tags exactly the same way. Put your template tags in `yourapp/templatetags/` directory. If your app is in the [`settings.INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-INSTALLED_APPS) that you can load it's tags by passing the module name to the [load](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#load) tag. It accepts also `package.module` syntax, so: `{% load somelibrary %}` or `{% load package.otherlibrary %}`

Comment: In otherwords, just put the template tags in a "templatetags" module in one of *your* apps, just as you would for other template tags. You can load them in the admin just as if it was your own template. It works the same way.

Comment: How add a custom tag to the Admin page? To I need to create custom templates to extend Admin?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to copy `templatetags` folder from `/django/contrib/admin/templatetags` in your virtual environment to `core` folder where `settings.py` is, then create `custom_tags.py` in `templatetags` folder as shown below, then don't forget to restart server to apply all `.py` files except `__init__.py` to Django project. *You can also override the code like the tags or filters in `admin_list.py`, `admin_modify.py`, `admin_urls.py`, `base.py` and `log.py` and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048232/what-does-load-do-in-django-templates/76250176#76250176) explaining [templatetags folder](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) and [load tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#load):

```
Django Project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-templatetags # Here
 |     |-__pycache__
 |     |-__init__.py
 |     |-admin_list.py
 |     |-admin_modify.py
 |     |-admin_urls.py
 |     |-base.py
 |     |-log.py
 |     └-custom_tags.py # Here
 |-templates
 |  └-admin
 |     └-model
 |        └-change_list.html
 |-app1
 └-app2
```

Then in `change_list.html`, load the custom tags in `custom_tags.py` as shown below:

```py
# "/templates/admin/model/change_list.html"

                                         # ↓ Here ↓
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_list custom_tags %}
```