# What is this Django template tag?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I'm working with Django and in the base template I see this: `{% get_cms_html_fragment "html/footer" %}`

From the surrounding syntax I can easily conclude that this is a footer include of some sort. But, it doesn't follow the traditional syntax of `{% block headerexample %}{% endblock %}` that is normally used in Django templates. Does anyone recognize this?

Answer (score 1):

In Django you can easily create custom tags. So it can be this very project specific tag.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 1):

This is a syntax for [a template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/). FYI, [`block`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#block) is one of the [built-in template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/), `get_cms_html_fragment` is a custom one.

Custom template tags and filters are loaded via [`load`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#load) built-in template tag.

See also:

- [Django: what does "load" do (in a template file)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048232/django-what-does-load-do-in-a-template-file)

Comment: Is there a common place that this custom tag is defined so I can edit it and see what it does? The `load` tag in my template does not correspond to any filename in my templatetags directory. `{% load cms_html_api %}` is at the top of the template.

Comment: @jefffabiny ok, then there is `cms_html_api` app that introduces the `get_cms_html_fragment` tag, check it.

Comment: There are a couple different settings files that are integrated together, and none of them have a `cms_html_api` in the installed apps section. There is this declaration that looks related though: `CMS_HTML_API_BASE_URL ='http://internal.network/the_api/content_fragment/'`

Comment: @jefffabiny well, this setting looks unfamiliar to me, it's probably one of your internal custom apps. Could you show your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting and the result of `pip freeze` command (inside virtual env if you are using it)?