# How to create a custom template tags in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, templatetags

I am new to Django and I am trying to create custom tags in django

my custom tag file `templatetag/custom_tag.py`

```
from django import template
from model_file.models import my_Model

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_custom_tag_fn():

    return my_Model.objects.all()
```

my html file

```
{% load custom_tag %}
    {% get_custom_tag_fn as queries %}
    {% for query in queries %}
      {{query.json_my_model_data}}
    {% endfor %}
```

I am not getting any output or error from this code. Can anyone point where I went wrong.

for extra information my `model.py` looks like

```
from django.db import models
from jsonfield import JSONField

class my_Model(models.Model):
    json_my_model_data = JSONField()
```

Comment: Are there any instances in `my_Model`?

Comment: `my_Model` doesn't seem to have a `val1` field.

Comment: sorry, I had made a mistake there it's not val1 its  json_my_model_data

Comment: And to answer to @WillemVanOnsem is, yes I have 2 objects.

Comment: Instead of iterating and run `{{queries}}`, I get `<QuerySet [<my_Model: my_Model object (1)>, <my_Model: my_Model object (2)>]>`

Comment: @BczImHappy: do the `json_my_model_data` contains any data?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem inside `my_model object(1)` I have value like `{"name":"joe","age":23}`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `my_Model` doesn't have a `val1` field, you may need to change your template to the following if you want to show `json_my_model_data` field in your data model `my_Model`:

```
{% load custom_tag %}
{% get_custom_tag_fn as queries %}
{% for query in queries %}
  {{query.json_my_model_data}} # to get model's `json_my_model_data` content.
{% endfor %}
```

On the top of that `{{query.json_my_model_data}}` will only be executed and show the contents of `json_my_model_data` if `queries` queryset has at-least one `my_Model` object from the database.

[More on custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags).

Hope it helps.

Comment: sorry. I make a mistake while typing here, actually, the value is  json_my_model_data in my program.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Django Template Tags. *You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223633/override-existing-django-template-tags#answer-76252238) explaining how to override existing Django Template Tags:

First, create `templatetags` folder with `__init__.py`(Empty file) and `custom_tags.py` in `core` folder where `settings.py` is as shown below, then don't forget to restart server to apply `custom_tags.py` to Django project. *Other names are fine for `custom_tags.py` and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048232/what-does-load-do-in-django-templates/76250176#76250176) explaining [templatetags folder](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) and [load tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#load):

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-templatetags # Here
 |     |-__init__.py
 |     └-custom_tags.py
 |-templates
 |  └-index.html
 |-app1
 └-app2
```

And, don't forget to set `core` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` to apply `custom_tags.py` to Django project as shown below. *Setting `core` to `INSTALLED_APPS` also can collect the static files in `core` folder to the root Django Project folder with `python manage.py collectstatic`. I recommend to set `core` to `INSTALLED_APPS` before you start building your Django Project:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'core', # Here
    'app1',
    'app2',
]
```

Next, create `uppercase` tag with [@register.simple_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) in `custom_tags.py` as shown below. *This time, you don't need to restart server because you have already restarted server to apply `custom_tags.py` to Django project:

```py
# "custom_tags.py"

from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.simple_tag
def uppercase(arg):
    return arg.upper()
```

Then, use the `uppercase` tag as shown below:

```
# "templates/index.html"

{% load custom_tags %}

{% uppercase "Hello World" %}
```

Then, this below is displayed:

```
HELLO WORLD
```