# How to see all possible attributes of an context variables in DjangoTtemplates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, modelform, templatetags

I'm trying to use double model form at once in one single view. I'm using django-betterforms to merge those. It merged all fields from two model in one single form. I know I can use different class and id to separate them but I can't extract them in template form, like:

```
{{ form }}
```

It will place full form in template. I can render all field like this:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field }} or anything
{% endfor %}
```

My question is how can I know all the possible attributes of this field like:

```
{{ field.* }} *=anything
```

kind of `dir(field)`.

I'm facing this problem but what will be solution to find all attributes or separate two forms in two side. Basically, I need to separate two model. Those will save at the same time with same view but in front-end those will be different.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What's wrong with ***`dir(field)`***? You can put that in your python file,

Comment: But I need to put that in template file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/):

**in templatetags/my_filters.py:**

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def getallattrs(value):
    return dir(value)
```

**in your template:**

```
{% load my_filters %}
...
{{ field|getallattrs }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create [a custom tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) to display all attributes of a context variable on Django Templates as shown below. *[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76246817/register-simple-tag-vs-register-tag-vs-register-inclusion-tag-in-django-templ/76246818#76246818), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223633/override-existing-django-template-tags/76252238#76252238) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048232/what-does-load-do-in-django-templates/76250176#76250176) answers explain more about custom template tags:

```py
# "templatetags/custom_tags.py"

from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_all_attrs(arg):
    return dir(arg)
```

Then, you can use `get_all_attrs()` by loading `custom_tags.py` on Django Templates as shown below:

```
# "templates/index.html"

{% load custom_tags %}

{% get_all_attrs field %}
```